# Stochastic matrix A^n=const.

Tags: stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $A\in M(n,n)$ be a doubly stochastic matrix such that
$$
A^k=\begin{pmatrix}
1/n & \cdots & 1/n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1/n & \cdots & 1/n\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $k>1$. Does it follow that
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/n & \cdots & 1/n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1/n & \cdots & 1/n\\
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Comment: You may want to check this paper: "Doubly stochastic matrices whose powers eventually stop", Linear Algebra and its Applications 330 (2001) 25–30.

Comment: $A^k$ has eigenvalue zero with multiplicity $n-1$, and 1 with multiplicity 1. So $A$ must have the same eigenvalues, with the same multiplicities. So $A$ must have rank 1. So all its rows are multiples of its first row. So all its rows are equal to its first row. Ditto for its columns. QED

Comment: Your proof is flawed; $rank(A)$ depends on the *geometric* multiplicity of 0, not the *algebraic* multiplicity. In particular, knowing 0 has multiplicity $n-1$ does *not* imply $rank(A)=1$!

But this led me to solve the question, so thank you for posting your argument!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of service, even when I was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

No, it **does not** follow that
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/n & \cdots & 1/n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1/n & \cdots & 1/n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Here is a (minimal) counterexample. Take
$$
J_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix},\qquad N=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2\\
-1 & -1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Observe that $N^2=J_3N=NJ_3=0$. Consequently for all $\varepsilon$,
$$
(J_3+\varepsilon N)^2=J_3^2=J_3.
$$
When $\varepsilon\leq 1/6$, $J_3+\varepsilon N$ is doubly stochastic, producing a counterexample in the case $n=3,k=2$.